# Pulling out values from element of array

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that is generated by IB-ruby and looks like this:

```
{:contract=>#<IB::Stock:0x0000560721a1aee0 @attributes={:symbol=>"AAPL", :currency=>"USD", :sec_type=>"STK", :created_at=>2019-10-23 23:03:35 +0200, :con_id=>0, :right=>"", :include_expired=>false, :exchange=>"SMART"}>, :last_price=>0.24308e3, :high=>0.24324e3, :low=>0.24122e3, :close_price=>0.23996e3, :open_tick=>0.2421e3, :bid_price=>0.2431e3, :ask_price=>0.24319e3}
```

How do I pull out the symbol `("AAPL")` and the closing_price `(0.23996e3)` for further processing?

Comment: Can you post some valid ruby code? If you copy the code you posted, paste it in REPL for example, it won't run. A [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be even better.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the formatting tools to correctly format the code, variables in your question. Doing so helps us better understand what you're doing. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" will help. Also please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 2):

What you posted is the string representation of a Hash.

This Hash has a key `:close_price`, whose value you can access in this way:

```
your_hash[:close_price] #=> 0.23996e3
```

The hash also has a key `:contract` whose value is an instance of the class `IB::Stock`. To access this object:

```
ib_stock_instance = your_hash[:contract]
ib_stock_instance.class #=> IB::Stock
```